# Mac: Any way to reduce memory usage of 'Terminal' app?

Tags: osx

I have a fairly large number of terminals open -> exactly 9, but each one has from 4-12 tabs open.  They have been open for a lengthy number of days.  Now, I see on the Activity Monitor that the 'Terminal' app is using 9.38 GB of memory.  I don't want to lose the history/setup of these and the rest my system, so re-booting is not an option for another week or so.

Is there any other way?  Can I found out which tab is using the most memory and just close the top one or two?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What is the "Terminal" app, and by curiosity why you right "Terminal" inside quotes, and the app part without it.....  ? What this means? Terminal app is a application that runs in terminal, or it is something like a X terminal for the OS X.

Comment: Yes, the "Terminal" Mac OSX application is something like X-Terms for OSX

Comment: Doesn't `ps` or `top` let you see me,ory usage by instance of a program? Or does terminal.app run everything in one instance?

Comment: Very better now, how many lines of roll your xterminal is allowed to save on screen, maybe the roll is growing too much, and i think you can configure it to save less lines!

Comment: The OP is asking about a Mac, @LucianoAndressMartini

Comment: Upload a screenshot from `Activity Monitor` and then, from `top` command used in Terminal!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your Terminal app in OS/X is configured to save all the lines of the current session since it was opened as long as it has memory. You must limit the number of number of rows saved by the Terminal app.

Please goto Terminal->Preferences->Profiles, edit your active template, and where you can see Scrollback, change the radio button from "Limit to available memory" to "Limit number of rows to", and place there a reasonable number (1000 to 2000 maybe).

This setting only applies to new Window Terminal sessions, I am afraid, so you must close the current ones, and open new ones.

Comment: This is exactly i am saying in the comments.

Comment: I do agree you were right on the money, but not "exactly"...this is not xterminal, not Linux, and these are the exact steps to do it in "El Capitan". They are not very intuitive, in my opinion...  Abraços!

Comment: but i know is something like a xterminal and not exactly that, see my first comment!  =] Thank you. Abraços!

Comment: This should be a global option in the app, and not hidden under *each*   profile...OS/X is getting feature creep as time goes by.

Comment: i have the strong suspicion that since recent it has a bug/design fault that lets it keep collecting even IF you disabled or restricted it. it doesn't write the files, but it has retained the same performance issues.

Comment: @FlorianHeigl Have not noticed it, however I was a late Big Sur adopter, still using Monterey and have a 16GB machine.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro thanks for taking the time. I might be at that point in life where i just need to reinstall ...